# Montage together five gifs

Tags: command-line, video, image-manipulation

I have five gifs all with the same number of frames and the same framerate. Is it possible to montage these together into one gif where each frame is similar to a normal montage of static images and is the next frame in the gif. Furthermore, i would want the first two gifs on the first row, then a space, then the last three gifs.

Answer (score 11):

If I understood you correctly, you want one animated gif that looks like 5 animated gifs playing in parallel, right?

[Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) can do that (and much more). Probably even in one line of code, but I'll do it in several steps. Lets assume your gifs are called `anim1.gif`…`anim5.gif` and are each 100x100 pixels.

```
#Combine anim1.gif and anim2.gif (first row)
convert anim1.gif -repage 200x100 -coalesce null: \( anim2.gif -coalesce \) -geometry +100+0 -layers Composite anim1+2.gif
#Combine anim3.gif and anim4.gif (1st part of last row)
convert anim3.gif -repage 200x100 -coalesce null: \( anim4.gif -coalesce \) -geometry +100+0 -layers Composite anim3+4.gif
#Combine anim3+4.gif and anim5.gif (last row)
convert anim3+4.gif -repage 300x100 -coalesce null: \( anim5.gif -coalesce \) -geometry +200+0 -layers Composite anim3+4+5.gif
#Combine all, leaving one in the middle empty
convert anim1+2.gif -repage 300x300 -coalesce null: \( anim3+4+5.gif -coalesce \) -geometry +0+200 -layers Composite anim_all.gif
```

The technique is described in more detail [here](http://imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_mods/#append) (“Layered Composition“)

The final result (with animations examples from the imagemagick web page) looks like this:
[image: animated gif]